# Prove that if a closed subset $S$ of an Euclidean metric space, then it is a countable union of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Theorem 2.41 in Baby Rudin states that "if a set $E$ in $R^k$ has one of the following properties, then it has the other two: $E$ is closed and bounded, $E$ is compact, every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.

So $S$ is compact, but how do I show it is a countable union of compact sets?

Answer (score 4):

If $S$ is compact, there’s nothing to prove, but in fact you **don’t** know that $S$ is compact, because you don’t know that it’s bounded: all you know is that $S$ is closed.

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $B_n=\{x\in\Bbb R^k:\|x\|\le n\}$, and consider the sets $S\cap B_n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the intersection of any closed set $S$ and the closed ball of radius $R$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: Don't understand how this helps, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thus, $S \cap B_R$ is compact for any $R$. So, you can write $S = \cup_{n \in \Bbb N} S \cap B_n$